# How to fix "invalid value", "divide by zero" and other calculation errors

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, runtime-error, nan

I'm using numpy to calculate neural network weights and nodes but almost every time i run into errors like:

- "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log"
- "invalid value encountered in multiply"
- "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp"
- ...

which most of the time results in values becoming "nan".

Because weights are initiated randomly I don't always get the same errors.

When I build small neural network(2 inputs, 4 hidden nodes and 1 output for example) I don't encounter these errors at all, but if I increase number of hidden nodes it breaks resulting in 'nan' being the value of everything.

I searched for solutions already but they didn't help. I checked that values are not the ones that will result in 'nan' but I didn't find anything.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, epochs, lr):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.m = self.inputs.shape[0]
        self.n = self.inputs.shape[1]
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.lr = lr
        self.hidden1Size = 64
        self.hidden2Size = 64
        self.w1 = np.random.randn(self.n, self.hidden1Size)
        self.w2 = np.random.randn(self.hidden1Size, self.hidden2Size)
        self.w3 = np.random.randn(self.hidden2Size, self.outputs.shape[1])

    def sigmoid(self, n):
        return 1 / (1 - np.exp(-n))

    def sigmoidDerivative(self, n):
        return self.sigmoid(n) * (1 - self.sigmoid(n))

    def ReLU(self, n):
        return n * (n > 0)

    def ReLUDerivatie(self, n):
        return n > 0

    def crossEntropyLoss(self, y, h):
        return - (y * np.log(h) + (y - 1) * np.log(1 - h))

    def train(self):
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            X, a2, a3, h = self.feedForward()
            self.backProp(X, a2, a3, h)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print('Cost at ', i, 'epochs: ', print(self.crossEntropyLoss(self.inputs, h)))

    def feedForward(self):
        X = self.inputs
        z2 = X.dot(self.w1)
        a2 = self.ReLU(z2)
        z3 = a2.dot(self.w2)
        a3 = self.ReLU(z3)
        z4 = a3.dot(self.w3)
        h = self.sigmoid(z4)

        return X, a2, a3, h

    def backProp(self, X, a2, a3, h):

        outputErrors = self.crossEntropyLoss(self.outputs, h)
        outputDeltas = outputErrors * self.sigmoidDerivative(h)

        hidden2Errors = outputDeltas.dot(self.w3.T)
        hidden2Deltas = hidden2Errors * self.ReLUDerivatie(a3)

        hidden1Errors = hidden2Deltas.dot(self.w2.T)
        hidden1Deltas = hidden1Errors * self.ReLUDerivatie(a2)

        self.w3 += self.lr * a3.T.dot(outputDeltas)
        self.w2 += self.lr * a2.T.dot(hidden2Deltas)
        self.w1 += self.lr * X.T.dot(hidden1Deltas)


NN = NeuralNetwork(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]), np.array([[0], [0], [0], [1]]), 10000, 0.01)
NN.train()
```

These values are just for test. I plan on feeding image data to distinguish digits but as far as I know it shouldn't break with these.

Answer (score 0):

So, following might render nans/errors:

```
# if n == 0, you'll have division by 0
def sigmoid(self, n):
    return 1 / (1 - np.exp(-n))
```

And here:

```
# log function is not defined for negatives, thus for h < 0 or 1 - h < 0
def crossEntropyLoss(self, y, h):
        return - (y * np.log(h) + (y - 1) * np.log(1 - h))
```

There's a lot of transformations going on, hard to trace where the values come from, but these would be my first guesses. `dot` will render 0 in case vectors are parallel - maybe that might help you as well.

So, I recommend printing traceback in these two functions in case condition mentioned above occurs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_tb

This way you'll be able to find out which iteration/function called caused such invalid condition.